# How do I upload to S3 a file that I've downloaded and unzipped via node

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

I've tried the following code however I'm getting an error: `Error: EACCES, open 'out'`

```
var out = fs.createWriteStream('out');
request(url).pipe(zlib.createGunzip()).pipe(out);
var s3obj = new aws.S3({ params: { Bucket: 'mybucket', Key: 'mykey' } });
s3obj.upload({ Body: out }, function(err, data) {                       
    context.succeed("Completed");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

node.js is asynchronous, so you have to do this:

```
var s3obj = new aws.S3({ params: { Bucket: 'mybucket', Key: 'mykey' } });
var out = fs.createWriteStream('out');
request(url).pipe(zlib.createGunzip()).pipe(out)
  .on('end', function() {
    var uploadStream = fs.createReadStream('out')
    s3obj.upload({ Body: uploadStream }, function(err, data) {                       
      context.succeed("Completed");
    });
```

Comment: that didnt work unfortunately, still getting the same error